# The displayinfochanged event is triggered only randomly in .net maui

Tags: .net, event-handling, listener, maui, screen-orientation

```cs
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    BindingContext = new CircleColorsViewModel();
    DeviceDisplay.Current.MainDisplayInfoChanged += Current_MainDisplayInfoChanged;
}
public void Current_MainDisplayInfoChanged(object sender, DisplayInfoChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("title", $"Orient: {DeviceDisplay.Current.MainDisplayInfo.Orientation}", "ok");
}
```

I change the orientation but this handler above is triggered only randomly, on some occasions. It feels so straightforward but many times does nothing. What am I missing?

Thank you.

Comment: I tested on my side, and it worked well when I rotate my phone. You mentioned that it does not work in some situation. So, can you provide more information?

Comment: This is on emulator. I've been trying with both Pixel 5 - API 33 and Tablet M - Api33. It just performs the event handler seemingly randomly, I can't figure out a pattern or ordering when it will or will not. (On the emulator Auto-Rotate is on.)

Comment: It is recommended to test it on the actual device. This might be an issue on the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a timing issue on emulator. Test on an actual device. Or try:

```cs
Dispatcher.Dispatch( async () =>
{
    await Task.Delay(100);
    Shell.Current.DisplayAlert(...
}
```

- `Dispatch` delays the action until after Current_MainDisplayInfoChanged returns. Allowing any internal Maui logic to run. [Code was already on UI thread; but UI thread might be in an awkward state at this moment. Theory.]
- `Delay` should ensure page is redrawn in new orientation before DisplayAlert.

Bottom line: I suspect that DisplayAlert attempts to run, but Maui's page renderer isn't yet in a good state after rotation. Maybe alert gets ignored because can't be completed (internal error that is quietly suppressed).

Comment: Unfortunately no. I tried 100, 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000 and finally 5000 got me excited for a minute because seemed to show the message box consistenly but then that didn't work either. The debugger won't go into the eventhandler most times. I don't understand. This is "the" emulator everyone is using, right? Was recently downloaded too. Maybe I should reinstall it.

Comment: If you can get it to fail on an actual device, that would be important information. But since it fails even with Dispatch plus long delay, it sounds like a real bug in Maui. You could create an issue at `github maui issues`.

Comment: 2 points: 1) I finally had a chance to try it on an actual device, and yes, the handler works in its original form. 2) I made the time interval with Delay function 10 seconds with the Emulator and it did the job "almost" everytime, missed one. So this will come down to my machine being slow I guess, won't it?

Comment: But it should print the message eventually, right? 10 seconds! Even my machine is not that slow. Yet the debugger won't go inside the handler at the missed times (happened once with 10 seconds). Could this be a show of what you said @ToolmakerSteve? You said "But since it fails even with Dispatch plus long delay, it sounds like a real bug in Maui." Something is going wrong with base.MainDisplayInfoChanged() and it cannot continue with my handler. Again, this is just with the emulator though.

Comment: Stop or kill app. Run app using its icon on emulator Home Screen. This runs without attached debugger (even for a debug build), so performance is improved. Success?

Comment: No. Still missing, and twice it missed more than 1. The UI is not updated as well when it misses. And after it misses, when I rotate the screen again it may say Portrait when it's actually Landscape and vice versa. What would actually still do for me is if it just skipped base.MainDisplayInfoChanged() because in my actual app the code is in place to care of UI in case of an orientation change. So I don't need base.MainDisplayInfoChanged(), which apparently is messing things up when on an emulator on a relatively small machine.